# AMPL syntax error that can not be solved

Tags: cplex, ampl

I'm struggling with the my AMPL syntax error. In my AMPL model, I have the constraint

```
subject to conpm_TM{tm in TM, t in T}: barpm_TM{tm,2*t} = pm_TM{tm,t};
```

here `TM,T` is the set I have already defined.

And when I run AMPL with Cplex solver, the AMPL says

```
syntax error   
context: subject to conpm_TM{tm in TM, t in T}: >>> barpm_TM{ <<< tm,2*t} = pm_TM{tm,t};
```

I am just wondering is this caused by my incorrect use of index `2*t` here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use square brackets, not curly ones for subscripts:

```
subject to conpm_TM{tm in TM, t in T}: barpm_TM[tm,2*t] = pm_TM[tm,t];
```